# Make Vaadin not scroll when replacing components

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a *VerticalLayout* containing two (big) components: a **grid** and a **chart**.
 The chart is updated according to the selection in the grid. I am using the *replaceComponent* method of *VerticalLayout* for this. So, when selecting an item in the grid, the chart is updated but the **browser scrolls up** instead of **keeping the scroll position**. This is probably because Vaadin first removes the chart from *DOM* and then adds the new one.

Is it possible to keep the scroll position while replacing components?

I didn't find any answer on the net so far. I can make a *SSCCE* if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to André I found out that setting a fixed height on the replaced component solved the problem. Here is a SSCCE:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    layout.setSpacing(true);
    setContent(layout);

    TextField t1 = new TextField("Big field (1)");
    t1.setWidth("300px");
    t1.setHeight("1000px");
    layout.addComponent(t1);

    TextField t2 = new TextField("Big field (2)");
    t2.setWidth("300px");
    t2.setHeight("1000px");
    layout.addComponent(t2);

    final Component[] toReplace = new Component[] { t2 };

    Button button = new Button("Click Me");
    button.addClickListener(event -> {
        Table t = new Table();
        t.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            t.addItem(new Object[] { "" + i }, i);
        }
        //t.setHeight("200px");

        layout.replaceComponent(toReplace[0], t);
        toReplace[0] = t;
    });
    layout.addComponent(button);

    setContent(layout);
}
```

When the height is not set, the scroll problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The [UI object](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.4/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#getScrollTop) has the `getScrollTop` and `setScrollTop` methods.

With these it should be possible to handle your requirements.
Before removing the components use `getScrollTop`to retrieve the scrollbar position, and after modifying your objects use the `setScrollTop` to the previously saved value.

Comment: This is a great hint but did not solve the problem. Even with setting the scroll top value after the component was replaced, the scroll position was like no replaced component exists. For reproduction I made that simple example (see my answer) and found out that a fixed height helps.